# WordPress function to add a class on a specific day

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

This code is used to add a class on a specific day. On that day, the class is well-added, but the next day this class disappears. Which is the right code?
I want to develop a function in a WordPress web to add a class on a specific day that does not disappear the day after.

```
function ProgramarBorrado(){
        ?> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var day = (new Date).getDate(); //Get today
            var month = (new Date).getMonth()+1; //Get this month
            var year = (new Date).getFullYear(); //Get this year
            var lista = [];
            if ((day == 1) && (month == 4) && (year==2019)) {  //Push ID on a list
            lista.push('#borrar22marc');
            }
            if ((day == 6) && (month == 4) && (year==2019)) {
            lista.push('#borrar6abril');
            }
            if ((day == 5) && (month == 5) && (year==2019)) {
            lista.push('#borrar5maig');
            }
            if ((day == 19) && (month == 5) && (year==2019)) {
            lista.push('#borrar19maig');
            }
            if ((day == 8) && (month == 6) && (year==2019)) {
            lista.push('#borrar8juny');
            }
            if ((day == 10) && (month == 8) && (year==2019)) {
            lista.push('#borrar10agost');
            }

            lista.forEach(function(element) {
                  jQuery(element).addClass('borrar-programado');// For each element on the list add a class on the ID
                });

        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'ProgramarBorrado');
```

This code is to add a class on a specific day. When that concrete day arrives he adds the class well, but then the next day this class does not appear anymore. What would be the correct code?

What I want to say is that the next day is eliminated, and what I want is that it never be eliminated.

Comment: Okay, after the next day it needs to keep it or not?

Comment: Yes, from next day until always

Comment: Do you mean for the year 2019?

Comment: I want to say this year and the following, that it be forever

Answer (score 0):

Why not extending your check for the specific dates? E.g.

```
if ((day == 10 || day == 11) && (month == 8) && (year==2019)) {
    lista.push('#borrar10agost');
}
```

Comment: What I want to say is that the next day is eliminated, and what I want is that it never be eliminated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

**Updated:**

```
function ProgramarBorrado(){
        ?> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var day = (new Date).getDate(); //Get today
            var month = (new Date).getMonth()+1; //Get this month
            var year = (new Date).getFullYear(); //Get this year
            var lista = [];
            if ( isNextDay(1, day ) && (month == 4) && (year==2019)) {  //Push ID on a list
              lista.push('#borrar22marc');
            }elseif (isNextDay(6, day ) && (month == 4) && (year==2019)) {
              lista.push('#borrar22marc');
              lista.push('#borrar6abril');
            }elseif (isNextDay(5, day ) && (month == 5) && (year==2019)) {
              lista.push('#borrar22marc');
              lista.push('#borrar6abril');
              lista.push('#borrar5maig');
            }elseif (isNextDay(19, day ) && (month == 5) && (year==2019)) {
              lista.push('#borrar22marc');
              lista.push('#borrar6abril');
              lista.push('#borrar5maig');
              lista.push('#borrar19maig');
            }elseif (isNextDay(8, day ) && (month == 6) && (year==2019)) {
              lista.push('#borrar22marc');
              lista.push('#borrar6abril');
              lista.push('#borrar5maig');
              lista.push('#borrar19maig');
              lista.push('#borrar8juny');
            }elseif (isNextDay(10, day ) && (month == 8) && (year==2019)) {
              lista.push('#borrar22marc');
              lista.push('#borrar6abril');
              lista.push('#borrar5maig');
              lista.push('#borrar19maig');
              lista.push('#borrar8juny');
            lista.push('#borrar10agost');
            }else{
              lista.push('#borrar22marc');
              lista.push('#borrar6abril');
              lista.push('#borrar5maig');
              lista.push('#borrar19maig');
              lista.push('#borrar8juny');
              lista.push('#borrar10agost');
           }

            lista.forEach(function(element) {
                  jQuery(element).addClass('borrar-programado');// For each element on the list add a class on the ID
                });

       // check for next day
       function isNextDay(day, cday){
         if(cday == day || cday == (day+1)){
           return true;
         }else{
          return false;
         }
       }

        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'ProgramarBorrado');
```

**Note:**  `isNextDay()` returns boolean (true/false) as condition meets.

Comment: What I want to say is that the next day is eliminated, and what I want is that it never be eliminated.

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will try it

Comment: After all, conditions meet, all classes will add forever.